# Why some data in binary file is shown as it is and other is shown in a strange way

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I have code, which writes vector of such structures to a binary file:

```
struct reader{
             char name[50];
             int card_num;
             char title[100];
             }
```

Everything works actually fine but when I, for example, write to file structure {One,1,One} and open .txt file, where it is stored, I see this:

One ММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММ   One ММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММ

So I was asked why is it displayed so, what it depends on, but I could'nt give a good answer to that question

**EDITED:**
Added code which I use to write to file

```
void Write_to_File(vector<reader>& vec){
    cin.clear();   // clearing
    fflush(stdin);// input stream
    const char* pointer = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&vec[0]);
    size_t bytes = vec.size() * sizeof(vec[0]);

    fstream f("D:\\temp.txt", ios::out);
    f.close();

    ofstream file("D:\\temp.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
    file.write(pointer, bytes);
    file.close();

    remove("D:\\lab.txt");
    rename("D:\\temp.txt", "D:\\lab.txt");
    cout << "\n*** Successfully written data ***\n\n";
}
```

P.S. When I read from file everything is ok

Comment: Show. your. code.

Comment: attach the code you used in order to write to file.

Comment: It happens because you made a mistake in your code. What mistake? How can we know?

Comment: Also curious as to how this counts as "working actually fine" to you

Comment: `struct reader` is some 154 bytes large (could be a bit more, due to padding). You initialize some 12 bytes worth of it; the rest remains uninitialized garbage. So that's what you write to the file - your data interspersed with uninitialized garbage.

Comment: You may wish to question youself on why you need to open the file, then close it, then reopen it again ...

Comment: @UKMonkey to create it, I guess

Answer (score 0):

You write 154 octets in a file, only One and One are char, so your text editor try to read char but get mostly garbage. You write binary, you should not expect to have something readable.

Answer (score 0):

> Why some data in binary file is shown as it is and other is shown in a strange way

It seems that you are trying to read the binary data as if it contained character encoded data. Some of it does - but not all. Perhaps this is why you think that it seems strange. Other than that, the output seems perfectly reasonable.

> why is it displayed so

Because that is the textual representation of the data that the object contains in the character encoding that your reader uses.

> what it depends on

It depends on the values that you have initialized the memory to have. For example the first character is displayed as `O` because you have initialized `name[0]` with the value `'O'`. Some of the data is padding between members that can not be initialized directly. What the value of those bytes depends on is unspecified.